# What is an efficient way to save or cache data from an API?

Tags: sql-server, api, coldfusion

I am building an web app (ColdFusion website with a SQL Server database) that needs to display data that resides on an external source and is available via API. Some of the data is "static", in that once it is there, it does not change. However, each day, new data is added. For example, let's say that the data represents "shipments". Yesterday's shipments are shipped and the data contained within will not change going forward. However, more shipments will be created today. Rather than call the API every time historical data is needed (for on-demand reports, let's say), I would like to save or cache the pertinent data from the API response, so that I can request it more quickly.

My initial thought is to write a separate ColdFusion script that makes a request to the API each day, retrieving the previous days shipments, parsing the data in the response and saving it to the SQL Server database.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, perhaps calling the API directly from the SQL Server database to import the data?

Comment: Is this an API that is called often enough that caching would be needed? Is there a lot of processing that causes this API to be slow? Can the data request be handled on the SQL server and just served to the CF API? Maybe with a reporting table on the SQL server that holds the data you need? Then just query that table directly.

Comment: For temporary caching to improve performance and reduce calls to the APi, you could use memcached or redis, among others. If you’re on AWS, I use Memcached on ElasticCache, which was super easy to setup.

Comment: @Shawn, yes right now he API is being called quite frequently to support web-facing reports. The API itself is not slow, but, at times the amounts of data are large, so parsing and processing and filtering the data uses a large amount of resources and takes a good amount of time. The data in question does not already exist in the SQL Server database. I am considering copying the data there to make querying easier. I am looking for an efficient way to do that.

Comment: @Redtopia thank you I will have to find this on the internet and learn more.

Comment: The approach you are considering has a very redeeming quality - simplicity.  I suggest sticking with it.

Comment: If you are having to pull the data from outside of your database to serve it back to your users, you might be better off with an out-of-hours process to pull the data into your system, process it, then store it in a new table within your database to serve up.

Comment: What version of CF and SQL?

Comment: I generating a unique key and then use CacheGet() & CachePut() to store API responses for a defined period of time.  (If CacheGet() = NULL, a fresh API request is performed and data is cached using CachePut() to temporarily store it.)

Comment: @Shawn, yes that's the plan. CF11 and SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment)

> My initial thought is to write a separate ColdFusion script that makes
>   a request to the API each day, retrieving the previous days shipments,
>   parsing the data in the response and saving it to the SQL Server
>   database.

Sounds like a reasonable approach. You just need a scheduled task that loads in the data and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the service through a .net program like c# and use a clr procedure. then create assembly dll and add it to sql server. then you will be able to set a job and schedule it to retrieve and save it into your table.

Comment: As I said above, I can do all of this with ColdFusion (create a job to call the API, parse the data and insert it into SQL Server). I am curious if there's a more efficient way to do this - i.e. directly in SQL Server.

Comment: Sounds like that's what the answer is describing - how to do something like that directly in sql server. (Not having tried it, no idea which is more "efficient").